# Copy single bytes of integer value to vector of unsigned chars

Tags: c++, vector

I receive an `int` value `foo` in a function from which I need to create an std::vector of `unsigned char`.
The size of the vector must not be larger than needed. That means, only if  `foo > 255` the size of the vector may be 2. If `foo > 0xFF` the size of the vector may be 3 and if `foo > 0xFFFFFF` the vector has to have a size of 4.
I can't seem to wrap my head around getting the right size of the vector depending on the size of the `int foo` and then accessing the correct bytes of the `int` to `push_back` on the vector.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

This is what I have so far:

```
    size_t foo2= foo;
    size_t bytes = 0;
    while (foo2!= 0)
    {
        foo2/= (1u << CHAR_BIT);
        bytes++;
    }
    std::vector<unsigned char> myVec(bytes);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        myVec[bytes-1-i]=(*((char*)&foo+ i));
```

Comment: Sometimes, Code examples communicates better...

Comment: Do you have any particular endianness requirement? Starting from the low byte and using `push_back` will, for example, make your vector little-endian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do it simple?

```
size_t foo2 = foo;

std::vector<unsigned char> myVec;
myVec.clear();

//special case if myVec should not be empty for foo = 0
if(foo2 == 0){
    myVec.push_back(0);
}

while(foo2 > 0){
    unsigned char current_part = (unsigned char) (foo2 % 256);
    myVec.push_back(current_part);
    foo2 /= 256;
}
```

And then maybe reverse, depending on the desired endian. (#include < algorithm >
std::reverse(myVec.begin(), myVec.end());)

(my code assumes that foo >= 0, btw, one might want to catch that or do an assert)

Comment: `foo2 % 255 ... foo2 /= 255` When calculating a decimal representation of a number, do you divide it by 9?

Comment: @n.m. Huh, sometimes I make some stupid mistakes. Thanks, changed that.

Comment: `(unsigned char) foo2` is already range 0-255, it adds nothing to use `% 256`.

Comment: @M.M I'm making mistakes all the day, it seems. Fixed that.